# In jQuery Mobile Select Menu, can I force the LI element have the same class as the underlining option element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

For example, if I have this HTML for a drop down menu:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="cars" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Select Seating Area</label>    
    <select id="cars" data-native-menu="false">
      <option class="myclass1" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option class="myclass2" value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option class="myclass3" value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option class="myclass4" value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
</div>
​
```

I want my custom classes to be added to the corresponding LI elements of the resulting UL element. How would one go about doing it? Does jQuery Mobile provide this functionality out of the box?

Here's a quick JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avQC6/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this functionality is not provided out of the box. The way to do this would be something like the following:

```
$('[data-option-index=0]').addClass('myclass1');
$('[data-option-index=2]').addClass('myclass2');
```

I'm sure you could write a neater way to accomplish this. That is just the general idea.

Comment: Because jQuery Mobile re-creates the UL's every time user presses the drop down, is there an event I could subscribe to to know when its done rendering?

Comment: Please disregard: the solution was to decorate the element with 'data-role="none"' and call .selectmenu() with custom options in JS. All is working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate or perhaps post your code in an answer to your own question. I am curious about how you solved this problem. A jsfiddle perhaps?

Comment: Just added a jsfiddle example. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The approach I ended up taking was the following:

- Disable JQM select menu handling by adding "data-role='none'" attribute to the menu
- Manually call .selectmenu() on the drop down list with a call back for "create" event

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PADH6/) for an example